# Setting sub-properties of border separately

Tags: css, google-chrome, border

I want to set the `border-style`, `border-width`, and `border-color` all separately. Particularly, I want to set the default `border-style` to be `solid` for the entire document, and set `border-width` and `border-color` for individual elements. I have an html:

```
<body>
  <div id="foo">
    bar
  </div>
</body>
```

and css:

```
body{
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px;
}
#foo{
  background: red;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: green;
}
```

The `border-width: 0px;` within `body` is intended to set the default element to have no border while setting the default `border-style` to solid (If I remove it, then the default `border-style` would be set as intended, but the body would have border, which is not intended). All the settings in `#foo` are intended to overwrite the default setting. When I display this, the border does not appear around  `div#foo`. Why does the border not appear, and what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The border styling is not inherited from the `body` element. You are looking for the [universal selector, `*`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#universal-selector), which will essentially apply the styling to all elements, thus serving as *pseudo-default* styling.

```
* {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px;
}
```

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/KmTLR/)

Answer (score 1):

I believe your first piece is applying a solid border only to the `body` element, and that the property is not inherited by its children.

Try using:

```
* {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px;
}
```

<s>You can drop the `border-width`, by the way, as the default value is already 0px.</s>

(edited to reflect comments)

Comment: Your answer was the first one that gave the reason why my code did not work. Upvote for that, however, your `border-width` part is wrong.

Comment: Setting `border-style` to solid changes the border width from 0 automatically: http://jsfiddle.net/Ckx9v/

Comment: Mm you're right. I was testing it by using Inspect Element on this page, which must have something to override the browser's default border width styling. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are setting the style of the border AROUND the body.  To set it for all elements of the body, you can use:

```
body *{
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px;
}
#foo{
    background: red;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
border-style: inherit;
```

to use the parent's border style. Or like @Anonymous said

```
body * {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0px;
}
```

for all children of body.

Edit: "inherit" means the value of its direct parent. Example:

```
<body>
  <div id="foo">
    <div id="boo">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

#foo {
  border-width: 3px;
  background: green;
  border-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
  // border-style is not set -> default value "none"
}

#boo {
  border-width: 3px;
  background: yellow;
  border-color: pink;
  border-style: inherit;
  padding: 10px;
  // border-style is "none" because foo's border-style is none
}
```

Comment: What would be the selector for `border-style: inherit;`? If it is to be `body *` or `*`, then it seems rather indirect than setting `border-style: solid;`.